# Multiple filtering pandas columns based on values in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df1`:

[image: df1]

Now, I want to filter the rows in `df1` based on unique combinations of `(Campaign, Merchant)` from another dataframe, `df2`, which look like this:

[image]

What I tried is using `.isin`, with a code similar to the one below:

```
df1.loc[df1['Campaign'].isin(df2['Campaign']) &
        df1['Merchant'].isin(df2['Merchant'])]
```

The problem here is that the conditions are independent eg : I want to check if `(A,1)` from `df2` is in `df1`, but with the above condition, since I am checking all the list, not row by row, it would return all rows in `df1` where `Campaign` column is `A` OR `Merchant` column is `1`.

Do you have any suggestion for this multiple pandas filtering?

Answer (score 2):

Bit late but my preferred solution to this is

```
# verbetim from @tuomastik

import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Random numbers 1": pd.np.random.randn(6),
                "Campaign": ["A"] * 5 + ["B"],
                "Merchant": [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Random numbers 2": pd.np.random.randn(6),
                "Campaign": ["A"] * 2 + ["B"] * 2 + ["C"] * 2,
                "Merchant": [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]})

# modification

def pair_columns(df, col1, col2):
   return df[col1] + df[col2]

def paired_mask(df1, df2, col1, col2):
   return pair_columns(df1, col1, col2).isin(pair_columns(df2, col1, col2))

identical = df1.loc[paired_mask(df1, df2, "Campaign", "Merchant")]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Random numbers 1": pd.np.random.randn(6),
                    "Campaign": ["A"] * 5 + ["B"],
                    "Merchant": [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Random numbers 2": pd.np.random.randn(6),
                    "Campaign": ["A"] * 2 + ["B"] * 2 + ["C"] * 2,
                    "Merchant": [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]})

columns_consider = ["Campaign", "Merchant"]
combined = pd.concat((df1[columns_consider].drop_duplicates(),
                      df2[columns_consider].drop_duplicates()), ignore_index=True)

identical = combined[combined.duplicated()]

print(identical)
```

Output:

```
  Campaign  Merchant
4        A         1
5        A         2
6        B         1
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I always go about it is by creating a lookup column:

```
df1['lookup'] = df1['Campaign'] + "_" + df1['Merchant'].astype(str)
df2['lookup'] = df2['Campaign'] + "_" + df2['Merchant'].astype(str)
```

Then use loc to filter and drop the lookup columns:

```
df1.loc[df1['lookup'].isin(df2['lookup'])]
df1.drop(columns='lookup', inplace=True)
```

I'm still looking for a better solution.